# Can't seem to quiet my disc brakes

Tags: disc-brake, hydraulic-disc-brake, brake-pads

I recently purchased a bike that clearly needed fixing, for a great price.  I've given the bike a bit of a tune-up, but one thing that won't seem to go away is the squealing sound coming from the disc brakes.  The brake pads look fine, but I went ahead and cleaned them with isopropyl alcohol and shaved them a little with light sandpaper.  I also cleaned the disc with the same alcohol, but the sound is still there.  The disc itself appears to be straight.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Maybe axel is out of shape or flex?  Guessing you’ve already checked calliper alignment?  Is it a constant noise or particular place in the wheel rotation?

Comment: Constant noise when brake is engaged, but not fully engaged.

Comment: So when the brakes are fully on they don't squeal, only when they're partly on?  Is it possible that the rotor isn't completely locked down?  (e.g. One of the bolts is stripped or cross-threaded.)

Comment: @DavidW the brakes do work to stop the bike just fine.  However, when I squeeze the brakes just enough to allow the tire to still turn, the noise starts continuously like a long loud moan.

Comment: Probably going to get myself corrected here, after reading your comments kind of think this might actually just be down to braking technique, all be it possibly exasperating another problem.  I've always been told; disc brakes should always be either on or off, not half on.  Other than that, might be down to the brake pad compound.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure I fully understand your comment @Hursey.  If you are going down a hill, you will need to put your brake on partially to slow down or am I not fully getting your comment...?

Comment: Being a bit tunnel visioned, didn't but should of asked about what type of biking you're doing.  I'm thinking exclusively MTB here, no idea how this applies to other type of riding, but maybe this article might give some in sight https://woom.com/en_INT/mountain-biking/riding-technique-braking

Comment: @Hursey Any decent disc brake can absolutely be half-on, in fact it's one of the advantages of discs that you can modulate any braking strength under any condition. Now, that doesn't mean it's a good idea to gently drag the brakes on an entire descent – this can overheat the brakes; releasing them when possible in exchange for harder, shorter braking is generally better than continuously braking at low strength. But this only starts to matter if you drop at least 100 m, or more, depending on the brake type – big 4-piston brakes are hard to overheat if you don't deliberately maximize heating.

Comment: @Hursey As leftaroundabout said, being able to control your braking with very good precision is one mark of a good rider. The idea of "brakes only on or off" is more of a macroscopic view to ride faster (you should wait to brake as late as possible). However, when braking, you most definitely need to be able to control braking power.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Front disk brake squealing](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/60113/front-disk-brake-squealing) and many others. please use search and peruse the most likely questions answers.

Comment: Please keep comments on topic and use them only for clarifying the question which is Dealing with brake squeal.  Although braking technique can be used to prevent squeal and mask the problem, its rarely the root cause of the problem.